# Turning a vertical D3 tree into a collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have this code which displays a basic tree that I am happy with, but I needed to add collapsing feature

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

```
function getData() {
    return {'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Beth', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'children': [{'id': 4, 'first_name': 'Seth', 'last_name': 'Fowler', 'children': [{'id': 7, 'first_name': 'Margaret', 'last_name': 'Dougherty', 'children': [{'id': 8, 'first_name': 'Jessica', 'last_name': 'Cunningham', 'children': [{'id': 14, 'first_name': 'Jade', 'last_name': 'Jones', 'children': [{'id': 83, 'first_name': 'Todd', 'last_name': 'Lee', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">1 son</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">1 son</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 71, 'first_name': 'Brandon', 'last_name': 'Bullock', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">2 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 9, 'first_name': 'Timothy', 'last_name': 'Parks', 'children': [{'id': 11, 'first_name': 'Kimberly', 'last_name': 'Rivera', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 19, 'first_name': 'Roger', 'last_name': 'Atkins', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 33, 'first_name': 'Jeremiah', 'last_name': 'Allen', 'children': [{'id': 46, 'first_name': 'Jennifer', 'last_name': 'Mckinney', 'children': [{'id': 50, 'first_name': 'Pedro', 'last_name': 'Lynch', 'children': [{'id': 53, 'first_name': 'Chelsea', 'last_name': 'Mcdonald', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 73, 'first_name': 'Stephanie', 'last_name': 'Deleon', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">2 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 70, 'first_name': 'Terrence', 'last_name': 'Pittman', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">2 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">1 son</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 51, 'first_name': 'Tammy', 'last_name': 'Rivera', 'children': [{'id': 61, 'first_name': 'Michael', 'last_name': 'Thomas', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">1 son</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">4 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 12, 'first_name': 'Sheila', 'last_name': 'Lowe', 'children': [{'id': 15, 'first_name': 'Carl', 'last_name': 'Woods', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 39, 'first_name': 'Jessica', 'last_name': 'Tyler', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">2 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 23, 'first_name': 'Scott', 'last_name': 'Sullivan', 'children': [{'id': 27, 'first_name': 'Debra', 'last_name': 'Nunez', 'children': [{'id': 36, 'first_name': 'Kimberly', 'last_name': 'Hooper', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 57, 'first_name': 'Christine', 'last_name': 'Love', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">2 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 30, 'first_name': 'Jill', 'last_name': 'Foster', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 58, 'first_name': 'Jeffrey', 'last_name': 'Fields', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">3 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 24, 'first_name': 'Joyce', 'last_name': 'Thompson', 'children': [{'id': 43, 'first_name': 'Michelle', 'last_name': 'Townsend', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 44, 'first_name': 'Thomas', 'last_name': 'Pierce', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 48, 'first_name': 'Anne', 'last_name': 'Vargas', 'children': [{'id': 75, 'first_name': 'Justin', 'last_name': 'Henderson', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">1 son</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 55, 'first_name': 'Hannah', 'last_name': 'Williams', 'children': [{'id': 79, 'first_name': 'Heidi', 'last_name': 'Lopez', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">1 son</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">4 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 29, 'first_name': 'Melissa', 'last_name': 'Kelley', 'children': [{'id': 42, 'first_name': 'Clifford', 'last_name': 'Torres', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">1 son</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">6 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}, {'id': 63, 'first_name': 'Christine', 'last_name': 'Rose', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}, {'id': 77, 'first_name': 'Morgan', 'last_name': 'Barrett', 'children': [], 'num_children': ''}], 'num_children': '<p style="font-size: 14px; color: #E6D2AA80; text-align: center;">3 sons</p><div id=\'circle\'></div>'}
}
function connect(d, i) {
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
            + "V" + ((3 * d.source.y + 4 * d.target.y) / 7)
            + "H" + d.target.x
            + "V" + d.target.y;
    }
const treeCanvas = document.querySelector("#tree"); // Assuming treeCanvas is an element with id "treeCanvas"

    var margin = { top: 300, right: 50, bottom: 300, left: 50 }
    // var margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 }

    // width = (calculateDimensions(getData()).cols * 50) - margin.left - margin.right,
    width = 5000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    // height = (calculateDimensions(getData()).rows * 200) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    height = (5 * 250) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
        w = 1380 - m[1] - m[3],
        h = 800 - m[0] - m[2],
        i = 0;
    
    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .separation(function (a, b) { return a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : 1.5; })
        .children(function (d) { return d.children; })  // Adjusted to use 'children' property
        .size([width, height]);    

    var svg = d3.select(treeCanvas)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var nodes = tree.nodes(getData());

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

        node.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 180)
    .attr("height", 120)
    .attr("fill", "#111111")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x - 90; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y - 60; })
    .append("xhtml:div")
    .style("width", "157px")
    .style("height", "120px")
    .append("xhtml:div")
    .attr("onclick", "centerChildOnScreen(this)")
    .style("width", "157px")
    .style("height", "auto")
    .style("padding", "15px 10px")
    .html(function(d) {
        return `
            <h1 style="font-size: 20px; color: #E6D2AA; text-decoration: underline; text-align: center;">
                ${d.first_name} ${d.last_name}
            </h1>
            
                ${d.num_children}
            
        `;
    });

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(tree.links(nodes))
        .enter()
        .insert("path", "g")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#E6D2AAF7")
        .attr("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
        .attr("d", connect);
```

I went through the documentation, but was unable to implement it in my code, because I am using D3 Version 3 and I couldn't find any helpful version 3 tutorials.

I am new to D3, and making this table was new thing to me alone.

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/Habibullah-Noori/pen/zYeLvpd

Cheers